# Clear cookie does't destroy passport session

Tags: passport.js, passport-local

i use koa-passport and passport-local

init strategy

```
  passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    (username, password, cb) => {
          db.findByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
            return cb(null, user);
          });
  }));
```

login

```
authorization.post('/login', function(ctx, next) {
  return passport.authenticate('local', function(user,error) {
    if (!user) {
      ctx.status = 401;
      ctx.body = { success: false, ...error }
    } else {
      ctx.body = { success: true }
      ctx.status = 200;
      return ctx.login(user)
    }
  })(ctx, next)
})
```

After delete cookies, browser still have access to private url and if i login again with same user then response does't contains "Set-Cookie" header with session id. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that happen because i use koa-proxy.
Auth logic is located on another server and i use koa-proxy for proxy requests. Now i delete koa-proxy and use http-proxy and http-proxy-rules and all ok.